# How can i protect profile form update by other users laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

This time i have Url like this 
**http://Blog/user/profile/51**
and i am logged in with a user whose **id = 51** but if i change this id to 50 it shows the form with data of user whose id is 50 i want to stop this how i can protect help please.
How can i check this condition before execution of othere

```
public function profile($id, Request $request)
    {    

  ***if($id == Auth::user()->id){
        Now Check get or post method
    }else{
        return ('Out');
    }***

$method = $request->method();
    if ($request->isMethod('get')) {
             $user = User::findOrFail($id);
            $users = DB::table('users')->select('id', 'name')->get();
            $user_fields = DB::table('users')->where('id', $user->id)->get();
     $page_data = [
                            'title' => 'Edit User Account',
                            'action' => 'edit'
                         ];

            return view('user.profile')->with(compact('user', 'page_data', 'users'));

    }else{
    $this->validate($request, [
           'name' => 'required|max:255',

         ]);

        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $input = $request->all();
        $user->fill([
        'name'           => $request->input('name'),
        'password'       => $request->password ? bcrypt($request->input('password')) : $user->password,
        'time_zone'   => $request->input('time_zone'),
        'address_line_1' => $request->input('address_line_1'),
        'address_line_2' => $request->input('address_line_2'),
         ])->save();
        session()->flash('msg',trans('successfully Updated.'));
}
```

i have idea that i can check auth user id equal to this id but dont know how to implement i am sanding url here as

```
<form action="/user/profile/{{$user->id}}" method="POST">
```

and i am taking auth user id here as

```
<a href="{{ route('user.profile', ['id' => Auth::user()->id ]) }}">
```

routes are as follows

```
Route::any('/user/profile/{id}', ['as' => 'user.profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@profile']);
```

Now how can i check before show form to user that is its related form or not
Thanks

Comment: why are you showing form of user 50 to user 51. Infact show 404 when user 51 trying to view profile of user 50.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make user profile private, you shouldn't tie it to `GET` parameter (do that only for public profile pages). What you should do it put profile route inside `auth` middleware group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('profile', 'UserController@showProfile');
}
```

And use `auth()->user()` object to get the data to display:

```
{{ auth()->user()->name }}
{{ auth()->user()->email }}
```

Comment: Kindly can you help me to set 
`if($id == Auth::user()->id){/////}`
If its ok then check condition for method get or post @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @recoverymen, I didn't understand the question. Can you please describe what exactly do you need?

Comment: I have update my question please can you help me to check this before check get or post mean if else in proper way 
`if($id == Auth::user()->id){
        Now Check get or post method
    }else{
        return ('Out');
    }`

@Alexey Mezenin

Comment: I wouldn't recomment you to do that, it's the a bad practice. You should really use separate actions (controller methods) and routes for public profile and private profile.

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel Middleware** ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware))

Middleware will help you out, it will allow you to check if the user requesting the url has the same id as stored in his session. If they match he's the 'owner' of the profile, if not you can redirect him an provide an error message.

*Create the middelware* (App\Http\Middleware\IsOwnerOfProfile.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class IsOwnerOfProfile {
    /**
     * Check if the user accessing the profile is the owner of the profile
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next){
        if ($request->id != auth()->user()->id) {
            return redirect('home')->with('error','You are not the owner of this profile');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

*Register the middelware* (App\Http\Kernel.php)

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // other defined middlewares
    'profileOwner' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsOwnerOfProfile::class,
]
```

*Update your route*

```
Route::any('/user/profile/{id}', [
    'middleware' => 'profileOwner'
    'as' => 'user.profile',
    'uses' => 'UserController@profile'
]);
```

NOTE & UPDATE:
As mentioned by @Alexey Mezenin the `auth` middelware is required to be executed before this one. Otherwise you will not have access to `auth()->user()` and the middleware will trow an exception.